# Anyone know a YUI-based Image Magnifier?

Tags: javascript, image, yui

Does anyone know of a YUI-based image magnifier?

I'm looking for something similar to the JQuery ["JQZoom" plugin](http://www.mind-projects.it/projects/jqzoom/demos.php#demo1).

Mousing over the image displays the matching portion of the enlarged version in a separate panel.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this one:
http://www.julienlecomte.net/blog/2007/08/9/

Doesn't exactly do the same as that jQuery plugin (magnification box is directly over the original image, like a lens, rather than being in a separate box)